# obiee 12c admin Tool not starting Error: bi_metadata_rt.dll file missing

Tags: oracle12c, obiee, oracle-bi

OBIEE 12c when trying to open the admin tool Error pops up.

[Error bi_metadata_rt.dll admin tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWOOg.jpg)

How to fix this, with out this I can't even start with rpd.

Please Guide.

Comment: If you can't locate that file anywhere on your computer, then see if you can install the same version of OBIEE on a different machine, then copy that dll to the needed path. But I'll tell you, I do not see this file anywhere in my own test OBIEE instance. Could this be from an older version (version 11g), in which case you should uninstall 11g first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this when I created a shortcut in my desktop.

It was due to the AdminTool not being lunched with the correct path.

You should try opening it from Start Menu -> Programs -> Oracle Business Intelligence Client -> biclient_homeX -> Administration

Comment: I got it,

I fixed this bug by myself.

The file location for admin tool is as follows:

`code` "@Oracle_Home"\user_projects\domains\bi\bitools\bin\admintool.cmd `code`